# How can I get my settlers off the roof without a mod?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, my Sanctuary Hills settlement has suddenly started having this problem where some of my settlers and Codsworth decide to throw a party on top of one of the abandoned buildings. They don't do anything but stand there.

Clearly it's a glitch. Googling has suggested a "spring cleaning" mod to remove the building entirely (it's the one that has the workshop in the driveway).

I placed a ladder against the side of the building and carefully climbed up (the roof is mostly holes), but while I can happily go up, my settlers will not come down. They really like hanging out of top of this roof apparently.

How can I get my settlers to come down without using mods? I'm open to console commands, but I'm trying to finish my first play through "vanilla" before installing any mods.

As a side note, this only recently happened after I fought off a super mutant attack at the settlement. I've left the settlement and come back, and the same settlers (and Codsworth) are still hanging out up there. The screenshot is the exact location of where I've propped the ladder, but they're just ignoring it.

[image]

Comment: Staircase always worked for me, but I found the trick was to place it then go sleep or wait an hour. They don't immediately walk down the staircase. In the end I just left it there

Comment: When you're not in a settlement, the engine moves settlers around without pathfinding. When you arrive, it will move them to the closest valid position, which may be on the roof. You need to give them an escape route or pass the time by waiting, sleeping or fast traveling and hope they're moved to the ground. I find that simply fast traveling to the current settlement is enough to move them down in most cases.

Comment: Try listening to their demands. Negotiate with them. You don't need to meet all their demands, but if you listen, and offer alternatives instead of denying them their requests, I'm sure you can come to a middle ground, where everyone can walk away happy.

Comment: I don't know enough about Fallout 4 but NV had melee attacks that could knock someone away. Could you push them off the roof that way?

Comment: @Studoku the entire settlement will attack you, and you'll either get killed or have to kill everyone.  It's not what you want to do.

Comment: Did you try simply yelling at them to [get off the dang roof?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJFa7NY0_wU)

Comment: @Studoku I tried the non-aggressive equivalent which is to run into them bodily which "knocks" them in the same direction upon collision. Unfortunately once they get close to the edge of the roof they just walk away to another part of the roof.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's the easy way. Looking at them (the way you are now), open the console. With the console open, click on one of them to select them and type into the console `moveto player`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will teleport the selected NPC to you (you'll have to close the console for it to take effect). Do the same for each NPC up there.

Comment: yeah!... bring the party to me!!

Comment: This ended up working for me, thanks. It also helped when my settlers at one of the other farms decided to run off and hide on *their* roof after a raider attack.

Answer (score 11):

There are many ways to get these people off the roof.

1. create stairs and wait for them to get off or go to sleep.
2. create stairs and add food, or create a scavenging station, or create a shop nearby.  Assign each settler to any of those.
3. create stairs and create a bell to call settlers nearby.  Ring the bell to call the settlers.
4. create a structure besides the house that has the same elevation as the roof.  Place a roof over it and add a tv and sofa in front of the tv.  Connect the structure to the roof or create stairs to get onto it.  Wait for them to go and watch tv.
5. create a drink stand far away from the house.  Assign a settler to it.  They will go there on their own before the end of the day.

Comment: I've always wondered / assumed that it's also important that the stairs be perfectly level with the surface so that no jumping is required to mount them.

Comment: 1. I created stairs and they ignored them, as I mentioned in my post. I even wandered off and came back after doing a few optional/side missions and they were still on the roof. 2. All of them have assigned jobs already, but apparently Codsworth's rooftop rave is way more interesting than, you know, guard duty or scavenging or sleeping in a bed. 5. I already have a drink stand. The bartender is hanging out on the roof. Along with my weapons shopkeeper.

Comment: Since they actually don't cause any problems in your settlement, maybe you can just leave them be for 30 or so in game days.  That usually resets the settlement.  It is a known glitch.  It is also on the steam forums.  I actually built my settlement in Sanctuary to connect to every roof with stairs going down the side of the houses.  At least you have not had a cow stuck in a doorway.

Comment: The cow-in-doorway was a different settlement. I love this game but the glitches and bugs are something else. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make stairs and then assign a settler to it. As soon as one settler goes down to do their job, Assign a different one to it. It saves resources.